# AppDomain ShadowCopy and impersonation - The specified user does not have a valid profile

Tags: asp.net, identity, appdomain

I have an ASP.NET web application using impersonation with the following web.config entry:

```
<system.web>
  <identity impersonate="true" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrators" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Independently, this works just fine. The user has to log in as an administrator, and when they do, the application can perform administrative operations on their behalf.

Further to this though, I want to isolate some operations in a separate AppDomain, and would ideally like to shadow copy files too. I set up an AppDomain like this:

```
AppDomainSetup appSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
appSetup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
appSetup.ApplicationBase = 
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

hostAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
    "AppDomain1",
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
    appSetup);
```

I then attempt to create an instance of an object in this AppDomain like:

```
var crossObject = (CrossAppDomainObject)hostAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    typeof(CrossAppDomainObject).Assembly.FullName,
    typeof(CrossAppDomainObject).FullName);
```

This produces the error:

**The specified user does not have a valid profile.  Unable to load 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.**

If I *don't* set the AppDomain to use ShadowCopy, the problem vanishes. Can anybody explain this behaviour?

To be a little more specific, I don't actually need to shadow copy *all* assemblies. Ultimately my `CrossAppDomainObject` will be loading assemblies from *another* folder using MEF, and it's these other assemblies that I want shadow copied. I suspect I can get what I want by configuring shadow copy to be selective in the files it copies. **But**, I'm still left wondering what causes this error.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than what assemblies are shadow copied, your problem is caused by the issue with 'where the assemblies are to be shadow copied to'.

Namely, not specifying [AppDomainSetup.CachePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.cachepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) causes the runtime, when shadow copying, to try to use a "user's download cache" location inside the user's profile directory (inside `C:\Users\`).

The error in your case is because Administrator is a special account that doesn't have such a profile directory.

One solution is to simply use the folder of the AppDomain running your web application, because ASP.NET already uses a specific CachePath (similar to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\d32f4325`), so that it works with such 'virtual' user accounts. If such a path is fine for you, just do

```
appSetup.CachePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.CachePath;
```